# how to check whether handlebar js is included in the application or not?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to check whether handlebar js is included in the application's HTML page or not. But it always returns **"Uncaught Reference Error - Handlebars is not defined"** even in the conditional statement. Guide me to achieve this requirement. Thanks in advance.

```
if(Handlebars){
      // do something with the templates written
}else{
     // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to access an undefined variable on the global scope will always throw a `ReferenceError`, but there's a simple solution - just replace `if (Handlebars)` with `if (window.Handlebars)`.

Comment: @KuKa: Glad to hear it!